# Django: ManyToManyField with intermediary model error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-intermediate-table

Django is not managing our databases for us, therefor I created the table `RulesetRuleMap` to handle the `ManyToMany` relationship between `Ruleset` and `Rule`:
Each `Ruleset` can consist of multiple `Rules` and each `Rule` can be used in multiple `Rulesets`.

### Models

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    percentage_of_total = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    _rule_parameter = models.ForeignKey('RuleParameter', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '_rule'


class Ruleset(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    rules = models.ManyToManyField('Rule', through="RulesetRuleMap")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '_ruleset'


class RulesetRuleMap(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    _rule = models.ForeignKey('Rule', models.CASCADE)
    _ruleset = models.ForeignKey('Ruleset', models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '_ruleset_rule_map'
```

### Serializers

```
class RulesetRuleMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = db_models.RulesetRuleMap
        fields = '__all__'


class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = db_models.Rule
        fields = '__all__'


class RulesetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rules = RuleSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = db_models.Ruleset
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rules_data = validated_data.pop('rules')
        ruleset = db_models.Ruleset.objects.create(**validated_data)
        rules_storage =[]
        for rule_data in rules_data:
            rule, created = db_models.Rule.objects.get_or_create(**rule_data)
            rules_storage.append(rule)
        ruleset.rules.add(*rules_storage, through_defaults={})
        return ruleset
```

On a homepage the user can add/modify a `Ruleset` and add/modify the assosiated `Rules`. On submission we receive a payload like this:

```
{
  "id": None,
  "name": "Split_50.0_Param1_50.0_Param2",
  "description": "test",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": None,
      "percentage_of_total": "50",
      "tc_rule_parameter": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": None,
      "percentage_of_total": "50",
      "tc_rule_parameter": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

As described in [Djange REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) I defined a custom `create()` for the nested `RulesetSerializer` to handle the creation of multiple objects. According to [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) one should be able to

> use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships, as long as you specify through_defaults for any required fields.

When executing `ruleset.rules.add(*rules_storage, through_defaults={})` I get the error

```
{TypeError}add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'through_defaults'
```

When executing `ruleset.rules.add(*rules_storage)` I get the error

```
{AttributeError}Cannot use add() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.Use database_models.TcRulesetRuleMap's Manager instead.
```

Is there a mistake in my model and/or serializer set up or is there a bug in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the django docs. I'm on django 2.1 and the through fields were only introduced in 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

As it says there:

> Cannot use add() on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.

You've specified your own through model, `RulesetRuleMap`, so you need to create the objects yourself because django doesn't support `add()` for this scenario.

If you want to use `add()`, `create()` or `set()` then, according to the documentation listed below, you need to pass the kwarg `through_defaults` for any required fields. You don't have any extra required fields, so debugging on your specific set of models would be required.

The DRF docs for this relationship with a through model are [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model)

There's a good example in the django docs for setting up the objects with a through model [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

In the example, there are 3 models, `Person`, `Group` and `Membership`. `Group` has the M2M to `Person` through `Membership`.

```
>>> ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")
>>> paul = Person.objects.create(name="Paul McCartney")
>>> beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Ringo Starr>]>
>>> ringo.group_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: The Beatles>]>
>>> m2 = Membership.objects.create(person=paul, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1960, 8, 1),
...     invite_reason="Wanted to form a band.")
>>> beatles.members.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Ringo Starr>, <Person: Paul McCartney>]>
```

Comment: Please explain the difference between the django models and mine @markwalker_ . The linked django example specified it's own through model as well and add(), create() or set() can be used on it.
Ruleset -> Membership, Rule -> Person , Ruleset -> Group

Comment: There isn't really a difference in the models. They specify two models which are M2M linked through a custom model rather than a magic django M2M model, just like you do. `Rule` is like `Person`, `Ruleset` like `Group` and `RulesetRuleMap` like `Membership`. You're right - the docs also show how you can use some of the builtin methods like `add()` and you don't have any extra required fields, so why django has a problem with what you're doing isn't clear without more debugging of your specific scenario